# I have a code and want a to return single value

Tags: python, pandas, set, intersection

I have a data frame which has a row called items, and I have a list called topitems. Below are some ex to it

```
Df.head()

Item
Toy
Car, Toy
Buses, Car
Bike
Barbie
Lorri
```

My list is topitems

```
[Toy, Bike, Car]
```

Now I want another column in the data frame called Top Item.

I have tried with set & intersection but they return two matching values

Against Toy, it returns Toy d against Toy and Car it returns Toy and car but I want it to return the only Toy

```
dff['topitems'] = dff.items.apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(set(topitems))))
```

I want the result to be like below,

```
Df.head()
Item         | Top item
Toy          |   Toy
Car, Toy     |   Car (note : i don't want the second value even though 
                       it's in my list)
Buses, Car   |   Car
Bike         |   Bike
Barbie       |   Blank
Lorri        |   Blank
```

Comment: maybe use index [0] to get first element from list. Or better `[:1]` to skip error when list is empty

Answer (score 2):

You can use index `[0]` to get first element from list. Or better use `[:1]` and it will not raise error when list is empty and there is no `[0]`

```
dff['topitems'] = dff.items.apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(set(topitems)))[:1])
```

---

Example code:

**EDIT:** I removed `set()` in `intersection()` as suggested @rpanai in comment.

```
import pandas as pd

dff = pd.DataFrame({'items':[
                        ['Toy'],
                        ['Car', 'Toy'],
                        ['Buses', 'Car'],
                        ['Bike'],
                        ['Barbie'],
                        ['Lorri'],
                    ]})


topitems = ['Toy', 'Bike', 'Car']
dff['topitems'] = dff['items'].apply(lambda x: list(set(x).intersection(topitems))[:1])

print(dff)
```

Comment: The second `set` after intersection is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

**Setup:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Item': {0: 'Toy',
                  1: 'Car, Toy',
                  2: 'Buses, Car',
                  3: 'Bike',
                  4: 'Barbie',
                  5: 'Lorri'}})
topitems = ['Toy', 'Bike', 'Car']

df
    Item
0   Toy
1   Car, Toy
2   Buses, Car
3   Bike
4   Barbie
5   Lorri
```

**Solution:**

You can first split the Item to list and check if each element is in the topitems list. Finally determine the first appearing item if any and fill na with 'BLANK'

```
df['Top item'] = (
    df.Item.str.split(',\s+', expand=True)
    .where(lambda x: x.applymap(lambda e: e in topitems))
    .bfill(1)
    .fillna('BLANK')
    [0]
)

    Item        Top item
0   Toy         Toy
1   Car, Toy    Car
2   Buses, Car  Car
3   Bike        Bike
4   Barbie      BLANK
5   Lorri       BLANK
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**: You can use pop(0) method to pop first element from the list.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'items':[
                        ['Toy'],
                        ['Car', 'Toy'],
                        ['Buses', 'Car'],
                        ['Bike'],
                        ['Barbie'],
                        ['Lorri'],
                    ]})

topitems = ['Toy', 'Bike', 'Car']
def pop_first_element(row):
    item = row['items']
    matched_list = [el for el in item if el in topitems]
    return [matched_list.pop(0)]if matched_list else ['BLANK']


df['KEYWORDS'] = df.apply(pop_first_element , axis=1)
```